# why jsp fires a PropertyNotFound?

Tags: jsp, syntax, struts2, el, ognl

Writing in a JSP:

```
${a.b.c}
```

throws 'c' PropertyNotFound, but writing

```
<s:property value="#a.b.c"/>
```

works fine.

I'd appreciate if someone can explain why `${a.b.c}` doesn't work?

UPDATED:

In the same JSP, accessing to another bean `f` such as `${a.f.d}` it finds `d` correctly.

I have checked that property `c` in `${a.b.c}` exists.

Comment: Check out this http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl.html

Comment: Thanks @looser your link was useful. However I updated the question to highlight that ${ } notation is actually finding other properties.

Comment: Is `b` instantiated ? Can you post B and C objects (just the minimal parts) ?

Comment: It depends on where `a` is coming from in the first place. The `${}` notation will search only the value stack, not the named values that are in the stack context, but not the stack itself.

Comment: Why do you need `$` notation, it's not necessary in the context above, so it could be slightly removed without further explanations, on the basis that it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Question.If you have not specified getter setters for property c in b then this error will occur `Propertynotfound` for

```
 ${a.b.c}
```

But

```
  <s:property value="#a.b.c"/>
```

will not cause an error. The difference is ${} works on getter setters as it is OGNL it reads using getter setter from valuestack.

Simply write getter setter in class b. ${a.b.c} will start working. For example if c is public String c then,

```
public String getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(String c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```