# calling an action method from a jsp

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

Simply..I need to know whether these list attributes are doing same job or not.

```
<s:select name="city" label="City" list="cities" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

and

```
<s:select name="city" label="City" list="%{getCities()}" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

can we invoke action methods like above,If 'yes' what is the correct way to do that?

thanks,

Comment: Both methods are correct, what is your problem?

Comment: where the places I need to use '%' sign in struts tags attributes and is it optional for attributes?

Comment: % is used where you can't do without it.

Answer (score 1):

`list="cities"` and `list="%{getCities()}"` both are exactly same. Both calls getter of `List<City> cities` in **action** class to read value from `valuestack`.

Both will throw an error if **getter** would be removed.

```
1. <s:select name="city" label="City" list="cities[0]" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

is evaluated to

```
a. <s:select name="city" label="City" list="%{cities[0]}" listKey="id" listValue="name" />

b. <s:select name="city" label="City" list="%{getCities().get(0)}" listKey="id" listValue="name" />
```

1, a & b are same because % forces `OGNL` evaluation. that will query stack for particular property.

OGNL supports collections, that's why we can use this three.

We call actions when we use particular need.

**For Example**

```
 <s:url id="databaseList" action="fetch-citynames" />
 <sd:autocompleter key="search"
     href="%{databaseList}" name="searchText" />
```

Here `fetch-citynames` return `json` list.

Also see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874470/why-jsp-fires-a-propertynotfound/23058600#23058600)

Actually I read from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_value_stack_ognl.htm)

[image: ognl]

The principal reason is because `%{}` syntax is used to force OGNL evaluation where Struts would otherwise be treating the value as a String literal.

**For example,**

```
  <s:property value="name" />
```

will look for a name property in the value stack i.e. is a value retrieved by calling getName().

If you wanted to force it to use literal value "name", you will need to use the `%{}` syntax -

```
 <s:property value="%{'name'}" />
```

But in the case of `<s:select list="" />` it uses [OGNL Collection Construction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Collection_Construction)

Here is how `OGNL` call methods.. See [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Calling_Methods)

Comment: They are NOT exactly the same.

Comment: The link isn't related with the question.

Comment: then I should delete this answer.

Comment: You can leave it but modify it.

Comment: More nonsense. Where have you found that `list` of `select` uses projection?

Comment: No i was updating it.. it uses `Collection Construction`

Comment: Also read `Interpreting Objects as Collections` and `calling methods` on that link

Comment: Again `list` by itself doesn't use collection construction or some else fancy named stuff.

Comment: I read there how `OGNL` call **methods** and how collections are **processed** during `%{}` expressions.

Comment: Aleksandr M Please modify this answer to be suitable for this question. I am little bit confused... now...